# String Manipulation in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am currently working on an exercise that will display a certain text, say TESTTEMP, from a series of characters stored in a column. Example of the string:

```
PROGRAMNAME|MAX2112ETI_L;PROGRAMREV|L;TESTOPTION|FR;TESTTEMP|25;STD IPH|528.63436123348
```

Now what I need is to extract the text past the string `TESTTEMP|` and before the `;`. What I did is I extracted all the text past `TESTTEMP|` and just get the first two character. Unfortunately, this will not be possible since there are cases where in the `TESTTEMP|` has 3 characters. Is there a way for me to be able to do this? Below is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, ';TESTTEMP|')+10), 1, 2) invalue
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    'PROGRAMNAME|MAX2112ETI_L;PROGRAMREV|L;TESTOPTION|FR;TESTTEMP|25;STD IPH|528.63436123348' VALUE 
  FROM dual
)t;
```

Comment: `regexp_substr(value, '(;|^)TESTTEMP\|(\d+)(;|$)', 1, 1, '', 2)`

Comment: Use regexp_substr as Egor said - it is more elegant way to parse the complex string than series of SUBSTR and INSTR.

Comment: hello denier, but this does not work on 3 digit and negative testtemps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index of ; in the substring and use that as index instead of hard coding it to 2.

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, ';TESTTEMP|')+10), 1, INSTR(SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, ';TESTTEMP|')+10), ';')-1) invalue
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    'PROGRAMNAME|MAX2112ETI_L;PROGRAMREV|L;TESTOPTION|FR;TESTTEMP|25;STD IPH|528.63436123348' VALUE 
  FROM dual
)t;
```

If that look messy, you can even write it like this

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(VALUE, 1, INSTR(VALUE, ';') - 1) invalue
FROM
(
  SELECT
     SUBSTR(VALUE, INSTR(VALUE, ';TESTTEMP|') + 10)
     VALUE
  FROM (
      SELECT
         'PROGRAMNAME|MAX2112ETI_L;PROGRAMREV|L;TESTOPTION|FR;TESTTEMP|25;STD IPH|528.63436123348'
         VALUE
      FROM dual) t
)t;
```

Based on comments - if you want to know if the string was found or not, use this query. `FOUND` will be greater than 0 if the string is found.

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(VALUE, 1, INSTR(VALUE, ';')-1) invalue, FOUND
FROM
(
  SELECT
     SUBSTR(VALUE, INSTR(VALUE, SEARCHSTRING)+10) VALUE, INSTR(VALUE, SEARCHSTRING) FOUND
  FROM (
      SELECT
         'PROGRAMNAME|MAX2112ETI_L;PROGRAMREV|L;TESTOPTION|FR;TESTTEMP|25;STD IPH|528.63436123348'
         VALUE,
         ';TESTTEMP|' SEARCHSTRING
      FROM dual) t
)t;
```

Comment: Hello Lobo, your code works well. I just have a question though. What if TESTTEMP is not on the string? I assume that it will return an incorrect value.

Comment: @GianIsTheName I changed the query to tell you if search string is found or not.